# ExampleComponent does not display in a new Laravel 10 Project with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have created a new Laravel 10 project with Vue using the following commands:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel vue3
cd vue3 
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

After starting the local server, I see the Laravel project as per `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`. To test that Vue is working, I added the following in welcome.blade.php

```
<div>
      <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

However, I don't see any output due to `<example-component></example-component>` on the page and I also don't see any errors/message in dev console. (If I make any other change in `welcome.blade.php`, that get reflected on the page. I don't know why the component is not working.

Here are the contents of package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "vite": "^4.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.37"
  }
}
```

And, my `resources/js/app.js`

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

 /**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
  *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
*/

// Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, 
definition]) => {
//     app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), 
definition.default);
 // });

/**
* Finally, we will attach the application instance to a HTML element with
* an "id" attribute of "app". This element is included with the "auth"
* scaffolding. Otherwise, you will need to add an element yourself.
*/

app.mount('#app');
```

Any idea, what's wrong or what I need to do to make the vue component work?

Comment: Are you using inertia? Laravel Breeze with Vue and Inertia?  If so, you should have `@inertia` in your `app.blade.php` file and then show your Vue apps via Laravel routes.

Comment: No, I am not using Laravel Breeze.

Comment: What about Inertia? Inertia was built just for this situation, to help bridge Laravel backends easily with Vue front-ends. Does your project use Inertia (as I previously asked)?'

Comment: But to my point, I don't think that you can just shove a Vue component into a Blade app and expect it to work.

Comment: I have a working Laravel 9 project that does not use inertia, however, I use components. Yes, you are right that they are not in blade files. I will check how they are used there and try to implement the same scheme. thanks for your help

Comment: A [helpful link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/how-to-display-my-vue-component-in-a-blade-file). If you've not seen the Laracast video on Vue and Laravel, you should. It is a bit dated but still holds very relevant and useful info.

Comment: I checked my Laravel 9 project. I have used components in blade files  the same as I have used in my Laravel 10 project, and it works (in Laravel 9 project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that 'vue-loader' is missing in my project. After installing vue-loader, the example-component started working in a new test page, though it still does not work in the welcome.blade.php